# Would a world twice the size of Earth be able to have similar weather patterns?

Tags: magic, weather, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality

The TLDR for this is if I have a planet that is twice the diameter of Earth, (so four times the surface area), would continental distribution have more effect on the weather patterns than the sun and distances between the equator and the poles?  Gravity is the same as Earth

More detail, this world is in a different universe that has magic, it's part of the universe from the ground up and has its own set of rules just like gravity, time, and space do here in our own world.  For the purposes of this question all you need is that magic interacts with gravity in a way that reduces its effect on smaller bodies but not on larger bodies.  To this end, the planet in question is roughly twice the diameter of Earth and has the same gravity as Earth, a planet the size of Jupiter would experience almost no gravitational effects from magic and neither would the stars.  Due to the effects of said magic, even though the planet is much larger, atmospheric pressure would be no higher than that of Earth, the magic is a constant effect throughout, it is simply an extra physical law that affects this universe on top of our normal ones.

The planet has an even spread of oceans and continents but overall it's around 50/50 land to ocean as opposed to the 30/70 ish distribution here on Earth.  There are three moons, two that are on a similar scale of Earth to our moon, both in a tight orbit with each other, the third is smaller and on the other side of the planet.  There is an active magma core with tectonic activity being similar to Earth, although some tectonic plates are much larger than we have here, volcanic activity is similar to Earth.

Atmospheric composition is similar to Earth, overall the globe is similar on average to that of Earth, meaning that some of the equatorial regions are just outside of the range that humans would be able to live and survive in anything other than very small numbers, if at all.  There are frozen poles similar to ours, but if you take into account that the planet has four times the surface area then again, the area around the poles that can sustain life is much further away from the poles than it is on Earth.  I'm making the assumption that the poles and very hot equatorial regions are the way they are because of direct influence from the sun mixed with atmospheric composition, similar to how things work on Earth.

So my question is, if I want similar weather patterns to Earth, would the even distribution of continents and having connected oceans to allow for a thermal/saline circulation be enough to have the weather patterns I desire?  Or should I factor in a variable that I've not yet thought of?

The two moons in close orbit are specifically so that tides are more variable, both moons at the right point in their orbit will cause very high tides, which would make coastal towns more of a challenge.  One thing I'm completely unsure of is how this would also affect the weather systems.

I'm aware that weather is seriously chaotic, so I'm just looking for something that's believable and feels like it would work in the setting described.  If there's something I've overlooked then I'd like to get it right now rather than after I've put in 200 hours working on maps!

Comment: A planet twice the diameter of earth would have 2X the gravity. If it only has 1X the gravity, then it has (if I recall correctly, someone check this) 0.25X the density. Either way, the weather patterns would be different and multiple moons complicate the process. Simply put, there's no scientific way to have Earth's weather on any planet that isn't pretty much entirely Earth-like. For the future, please note that (a) You're allowed one and only one question per post. (b) Questions are expected to be narrowly scoped. Climate is very complex. Try to be specific.

Comment: So gravity has a lower affect on smaller particles, meaning it's pull on tiny gas particles is much lower?  Which in turn means you have less total atmosphere spread over twice the surface area?  Even if you presume gravity pulled just as well on gas and you had the same total atmospheric gas spreading it over twice the surface would thin it greatly.  I think humans could still breath at sea level, though they likely would get winded faster due to the lower density of air.  Anyone trying to cross a mountain, or possible even a decent sized hill, will suffocate though...

Comment: Please clarify the situation with the moons.  Are the two larger ones each orbiting the planet independently or are they somehow a binary-moon-system in orbit around the planet?  How can the smallest moon be consistently on the other side of the planet to the other moons?  A simple diagram showing the orbits would be useful.  Separate to the moon issue, does the planet have any axial tilt?

Comment: @jbh it's an alternate universe, so ignore our gravity rules, for this particular world the density of the planet is the same as earth, it's just bigger.

Comment: @dsollen The gravity exerted by the planet onto the gas particles would be the same as Earth.  The gravity changes in this universe would mean that a planet the size of earth would exert much less gravitational pull on you or objects on it, so it would give you half the gravity that is in our universe.  Gas particles on the planet would behave in much the same way as here, due to the overall 1G experienced across the surface.  Any differences that might occur don't matter for the story, as all creatures on the planet evolved to live there

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 The two larger moons are a binary moon system orbiting each other, and then in turn are orbiting the planet.  The smaller one just happens to have the same orbital path and timing, so is always on the opposite side of the planet.  However, that's not set in stone, it's an idea I was toying with and haven't looked into any real life examples of anything similar yet.  I want this world to resemble ours as closely as possible, but at the same time having the physical rules changed just enough to allow the larger planet

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 apologies I almost forgot, there is some axial tilt, it's roughly 29.5 compared to Earth's at 23.5.  I chose that number because it is roughly one quarter more than the tilt on Earth, which alone would give more severe seasonal variation.  On top of that, I'm making the assumption that the larger surface area of the planet would increase the effect of the seasonal variation much more markedly closer to the poles

Comment: @JBH Half the density (not a quarter) at twice the radius is sufficient for equal surface gravity.

Comment: You don't need magic at all to get earth like surface gravity on a super earth. Just get rid of the iron core and you are more or less done.

Comment: @Frithgar as someone that pounces on evolution based questions well, 'everyone evolved for lower atmosphere' isn't really a sufficient answer.  Lower atmosphere puts limits on what one can do.  For instance while I don't know the physics well enough to say for sure I'm pretty confident a bird simply couldn't fly in such a low atmosphere.   Larger animals like elephants couldn't exist because they would suffocate unless the percentage of oxygen with the atmosphere was significantly increased, which would in turn change how things rust or combust etc.  evolution can't change physical limits!

Comment: @Frithgar If we ignore the gravity rules, then the weather is any pattern you want. What's the point of the question?

Comment: @JBH This is a fantasy world that doesn't exist in our universe, the planet is twice the size of earth, with 1G being felt on the surface.  There are basic rules that I outlined to allow for this.  My question isn't about how the laws of gravity work, it's about weather patterns on a larger scale that what we have on this planet.

Comment: @dsollen I fully accept that large changes would mean exactly as you say, however the gravity on the surface of this planet is the same as the gravity on Earth.  The atmosphere isn't thinner or spread out, it's the same as on Earth.  I might have this completely wrong, but if the planet exerted the same amount of gravitational pull as Earth, but the air molecules exerted less pull than the ones here on Earth, the overall result would be so small a difference between the two as to be imperceptable.  My comment about evolution was allowing for maybe a 5-10% difference at most

Comment: @JBH I do understand that there's a lot more to gravity than just what I've outlined, but the basic gist of it in the universe I'm building is that magic acts as a constant additional law of physics, which has this interaction with gravity, thus giving us the planet at this size.  All other forces are the same as here, the only difference is that the planet is twice the size, but with the same gravitational force on the surface

Comment: @Frithgar I understand that, too. Please understand my point. You appear to be asking nothing more than, "please explain weather to me." That's not the job of any Stack Exchange site. As you gain experience and reputation on the Stack, we'll hold you to Stack Exchange's expectations more tightly. In short, you don't appear to have had an actual problem to solve because it could trivially be solved via magic.

Comment: @Frithgar the amount of gravity you have decides how many air molecules you can 'capture' and pull into your orbit.  The total number of air molecules that end up making up your atmosphere is thus almost entirely defined by how strong your gravity and you will have almost the same number of molecules on your earth since it has the same gravity.  Catch is you're world is twice as large, the same number of molecules are being spread over a much larger area and thus it's being spread thin by the need to cover so much area.  Unless you tweak your magic to justify more atmosphere captured and held.

Comment: @dsollen I didn't realise it worked like this, I will have to have a think about how that might be overcome, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earth has 3 large scale [atmospheric circulation Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_circulation) – the Hadley, Ferrel and Polar cells in each hemisphere:

These effect [wind patterns and the weather](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dale-Griffin-2/publication/319999478/figure/fig1/AS:558132322672640@1510080523145/1-Global-wind-circulation-patterns-1-Hadley-cell-2-Ferrel-cell-3-Polar-cell.png)

Jupiter has [8 Ferrel cells](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/pia24965-atmospheric-circulation-cells-on-earth-and-jupiter) in addition to a Hadley and Polar cell in each hemisphere

The exact calculations are probably highly complex but [this reference](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/992/what-factors-determine-the-number-of-hadley-cells-for-a-planet) provides some indication if you are interested in calculations

So it is possible that your super earth might have an additional Ferrel atmospheric circulation cell in each hemisphere. This would produce more bands of jet streams effecting the weather, more latitudes of “trade winds”, more areas of doldrums etc. So tropical zone, hot temperate, cold temperate and polar zones. In short your super earth would have a more nuanced and detailed weather and climate than would be expected of just creating a giant version of what we see on Earth.

One note of caution, anything can be achieved with magic including wrecking a story, so use it sparingly where you really need it, keep it consistent and keep the rest well bounded by reality. And welcome to world building.

Comment: I will read up some more about the Ferrel cells, thank you!  And I'll also keep the word of caution in mind about the use of magic, much appreciated

Answer (score -2):

> Would a world twice the size of Earth be able to have similar weather patterns?

With magic you can have anything you want there's no need to go into exhaustive details. You can have a World on top of a giant turtle and be a best seller. Your World is fairly mundane.

Comment: Yes magic can handwave everything, but not everyone wants to just handwave things without thought.  The very fact that the OP asked this question implies they wanted to more precisely define their magic and see the results of their world given those rules they set for their magic, not be told to ignore their own question.  You could answer half the questions on this site with "a wizard did it" in theory, but that doesn't mean it's a *useful* answer.